# ISingleResult and IEnumerable

Tags: c#

Can anyone explain what is **ISingleResult** and what is the difference between **ISingleResult** and **IEnumerable**. And when should we use it?.Please Explain this code.

```
public ISingleResult<CityMaster> SelectCityMaster()
    {
        try
        {
            return _ObjLinq.SelectCityMaster();
        }
        catch { throw; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Linq2Sql thing. Basically, it says that the query will return one table, not two or three.